# Changes to upload_max_filesize in Amazon Linux AMI php.ini will not take effect

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, ec2-ami

No matter what I seem to do on my php.ini file to adjust the upload file size, my WordPress size won't change from 2MB.

I've installed WordPress myself on the instance following some AWS tutorials.

Here's what I have done so far:

Create a PHP file in the Apache document root
Verified the loaded php.ini files location
PHP version 7.2.11

```
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini

Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d

Additional .ini files parsed:

/etc/php.d/20-bz2.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini
```

There are several other ini files parsed but on my Amazon Linux AMI instance, there is only one php.ini file

I use Sudo nano php.ini in the /etc directory

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
memory_limit = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

Save.
No errors.

```
Sudo service httpd restart
```

Look at my phpinfo.php page

It's showing 2MB
WordPress confirms the max upload size is 2MB

I have tried editing my .htaccess file but it seems to blow up my site if I add in solutions I've found regarding file upload size at the .htaccess file.

I have tried editing the wp-config.php file as well.  Same result  Seems to blow up the site.

I have full access to the instance.  I can and have saved the php.ini

It should work but simply does not.

Could it be that PHP 7x deals with this differently?

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem and fixed it by doing a few things:

First create a file `sudo nano /etc/php.d/zzz.ini`

Inside add the following:

```
upload_max_filesize=64M
post_max_size=64M
max_execution_time=100
```

Then the important command is: `sudo service php-fpm restart`

On most EC2 machines I use for clients usually a: `sudo service httpd restart` is enough but for some reason here it wasn't working.

Comment: Thank you, I have been looking for hours, I didn't need the new zzz.ini, using sudo service httpd restart was not enough for me, in the moment I used sudo service php-fpm restart the problem has been solved, now I just have a problem with post_max_size, doesn't matter what I put in that value, the server has is always as 32M even using php -i | grep -i "upload\_max\_filesize\|post\_max\_size\|max\_file\_uploads" without the restart shows me the updates in filesize but not in post size

Answer (score 0):

Same here! With same config, I even created a new file on /etc called **zzz.ini** where only put the same variables as you set up. After that:

```
sudo systemctl httpd restart
```

no errors... and the **php --ini**

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/20-bz2.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-xml.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-wddx.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php.d/zzz.ini
```

zzz.ini content:

```
post_max_size = 20M
upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

but on phpinfo() still gettinf max_upload_size = 2M ...